# Numpy's genfromtxt returns different structured data depending on dtype parameters

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

I have the following:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt    
seg_data1 = genfromtxt('./datasets/segmentation.all', delimiter=',', dtype="|S5")
seg_data2 = genfromtxt('./datasets/segmentation.all', delimiter=',', dtype=["|S5"] + ["float" for n in range(19)])

print seg_data1
print seg_data2

print seg_data1[:,0:1]
print seg_data2[:,0:1]
```

it turns out that `seg_data1` and `seg_data2` are not the same kind of structure. Here's what printed:

```
[['BRICK' '140.0' '125.0' ..., '7.777' '0.545' '-1.12']
 ['BRICK' '188.0' '133.0' ..., '8.444' '0.538' '-0.92']
 ['BRICK' '105.0' '139.0' ..., '7.555' '0.532' '-0.96']
 ..., 
 ['CEMEN' '128.0' '161.0' ..., '10.88' '0.540' '-1.99']
 ['CEMEN' '150.0' '158.0' ..., '12.22' '0.503' '-1.94']
 ['CEMEN' '124.0' '162.0' ..., '14.55' '0.479' '-2.02']]
[ ('BRICK', 140.0, 125.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2777779, 0.06296301, 0.66666675, 0.31111118, 6.185185, 7.3333335, 7.6666665, 3.5555556, 3.4444444, 4.4444447, -7.888889, 7.7777777, 0.5456349, -1.1218182)
 ('BRICK', 188.0, 133.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.33333334, 0.26666674, 0.5, 0.077777736, 6.6666665, 8.333334, 7.7777777, 3.8888888, 5.0, 3.3333333, -8.333333, 8.444445, 0.53858024, -0.92481726)
 ('BRICK', 105.0, 139.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.27777782, 0.107407436, 0.83333325, 0.52222216, 6.111111, 7.5555553, 7.2222223, 3.5555556, 4.3333335, 3.3333333, -7.6666665, 7.5555553, 0.5326279, -0.96594584)
 ...,
 ('CEMEN', 128.0, 161.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.55555534, 0.25185192, 0.77777785, 0.16296278, 7.148148, 5.5555553, 10.888889, 5.0, -4.7777777, 11.222222, -6.4444447, 10.888889, 0.5409177, -1.9963073)
 ('CEMEN', 150.0, 158.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.166667, 1.6333338, 1.388889, 0.41851807, 8.444445, 7.0, 12.222222, 6.111111, -4.3333335, 11.333333, -7.0, 12.222222, 0.50308645, -1.9434487)
 ('CEMEN', 124.0, 162.0, 9.0, 0.11111111, 0.0, 1.3888888, 1.1296295, 2.0, 0.8888891, 10.037037, 8.0, 14.555555, 7.5555553, -6.111111, 13.555555, -7.4444447, 14.555555, 0.4799313, -2.0293121)]
[['BRICK']
 ['BRICK']
 ['BRICK']
 ..., 
 ['CEMEN']
 ['CEMEN']
 ['CEMEN']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "segmentationdata.py", line 14, in <module>
    print seg_data2[:,0:1]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I'd rather have `genfromtxt` return data in the form of `seg_data1`, though I don't know of any built-in way to force `seg_data2` to conform to that type. As far as I know there's no easy way to do:

```
seg_target1 = seg_data1[:,0:1]
seg_data1 = seg_data1[:,1:]
```

for `seg_data2`. Now I could do `data.astype(float)` but the point is, isn't that what `genfromtxt` should have done to begin with when I gave it that `dtype` array?

Comment: what the heck is `["|S5"] + ["float" for n in range(19)]` suppose to represent for the dtype?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. You're saying that you'd *"rather have `genfromtxt` return data in the form of `seg_data1`"*, so what's wrong with `seg_data1` as you've generated it? It looks like you might be confusing *fields* in a structured array with *columns* in a  multidimensional array. Fields can have different dtypes but columns cannot. If you want a data structure where the "columns" can have different dtypes then you might want to use a [`pandas.DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) instead.

Comment: Does a `panda.DataFrame` use a structured array to store its data?  Or a `dtype=object` array?  Or either depending on what's convenient?

Comment: @hpaulj Depends - I think it can be any type of ndarray, including both structured and object arrays.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen it represents the first column being a string, and the rest of the columns being floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dtype="|S5"` you import all columns as strings (5 char).  The result is a 2d array with rows like

```
['BRICK' '140.0' '125.0' ..., '7.777' '0.545' '-1.12']
```

With `dtype=["|S5"] + ["float" for n in range(19)]` you specify the dtype for each column, the result is a structured array.  It is 1d with 20 fields.  You access the fields by name (look at `set_data2.dtype`), not by column number.

A element, or record, of this array is displayed as a tuple, and includes a string and 19 floats:

```
('BRICK', 140.0, 125.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2777779, 0.06296301, 0.66666675, 0.31111118, 6.185185, 7.3333335, 7.6666665, 3.5555556, 3.4444444, 4.4444447, -7.888889, 7.7777777, 0.5456349, -1.1218182)
```

# the initial character column

```
print set_data2['f0']
```

Specifying `dtype=None` should produce the same thing, possibly with some integer columns instead of all floats.

It is also possible to specify a `dtype` with 2 fields, one the string column, and the other the 19 floats.  I'd have to check the docs and run a few test cases to be sure of the format.

I think you read enough of `genfromtxt` docs to see that you could specify a compound dtype, but not enough to understand the results.

=================

Example of importing csv with text and numbers:

```
In [139]: txt=b"""one 1 2 3
     ...: two 4 5 6
     ...: """
```

default: all floats

```
In [140]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines())
Out[140]: 
array([[ nan,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [ nan,   4.,   5.,   6.]])
```

automatic dtype selection - 4 fields

```
In [141]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=None)
Out[141]: 
array([(b'one', 1, 2, 3), (b'two', 4, 5, 6)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S3'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

user specified field dtypes

```
In [142]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype='str,int,float,int')
Out[142]: 
array([('', 1, 2.0, 3), ('', 4, 5.0, 6)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<U'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<i4')])
```

Compound dtype, with column count for the numeric field (and correction to string column)

```
In [145]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype='S5,(3)int')
Out[145]: 
array([(b'one', [1, 2, 3]), (b'two', [4, 5, 6])], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', '<i4', (3,))])

In [146]: _['f0']
Out[146]: 
array([b'one', b'two'], 
      dtype='|S5')

In [149]: _['f1']
Out[149]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

If you need to do math across the numeric fields, this last case (or something more elaborate) might be most convenient.

To generate something more complicated it may be best to develop the `dtype` in a separate expression (dtype syntax can be tricky)

```
In [172]: dt=np.dtype([('f0','|S5'),('f1',[('f10',int),('f11',float,(2))])])

In [173]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),dtype=dt)
Out[173]: 
array([(b'one', (1, [2.0, 3.0])), (b'two', (4, [5.0, 6.0]))], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S5'), ('f1', [('f10', '<i4'), ('f11', '<f8', (2,))])])
```